# Erro em Assembly Intel/NASM (invalid combination of opcode and operands)

Tags: assembly, nasm

Na hora de montar o código abaixo, estou recebendo o erro `error: invalid combination of opcode and operands` nas linhas 16, 26 e 28.

```
SECTION .data

maior: db 0


SECTION .text

global retorna_numeros

retorna_numeros:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov ebx, [ebp+12] ;ebx = L = 3
    mov esi, [ebp+8]  ;esi = matriz 3x3
    mov maior, [esi]  ;*** linha 16 ***

    mov ecx, 0 ;i = 0

loop:
    mov eax, ecx ;eax = i
    mul ebx ;3*i
    add eax, eax ;eax = 3*i+i

    lea edx, [esi + 4*eax]   ;carregando endereço do elemento atual da matriz em edx
    cmp maior, [edx]         ;*** linha 26 ***
    jae end_loop             ;se a variável 'maior' for maior ou igual que o elemento atual da matriz, pula para o final do loop
    mov maior, [edx]         ;*** linha 28 ***

end_loop:
    inc ecx
    cmp ecx, ebx
    jb loop

    mov eax, maior

end:
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Alguém saberia me dizer o motivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode fazer operações `mov` e `cmp` com os dois operandos apontando para memória. Além disso, o endereço de destino precisa estar entre colchetes.

Então, resumindo, você precisa primeiro mover o conteúdo da memória para um registrador e depois do registrador para a memória.

```
; ...
mov eax, [esi]
mov [maior], eax
; ...
```

A mesma coisa precisa ser feita para o operador `cmp`.